# Expression Engine: Why is the Session ID part of the URL

Tags: expressionengine

I am in the process of updating an EE site on a dev server. I copied the database and all the core files over and in testing the links many (not all) are coming up with the session number in the middle of the URL as follows:

> http://dev.myurl.com/S=169fe023498b4203567a5c3db2629348c99908d1/blog

I have never seen this before and it breaks the links. Any clue what is causing this and more importantly how I can get rid of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, FMZ, since you're seeing this behavior on some links and not others, can you provide a template example for one of the links that is causing this issue? Failing that, have you tried temporarily turning off Session data in the CP and visiting that same link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a preference under **Admin** > **Security and Privacy** > **Security and Sessions**.

Set **User Session Type** to **Cookies only**. Any selection that contains **Session ID** will use a token in the URL to track the user's session.

If you're using config-file overrides, this triggers the same thing:

```
$config['user_session_type'] = "c";
```

Answer (score 1):

In the EE control panel, if you go to Admin -> Security & Privacy -> Security & Session Preferences, what do you have under "User Session Type"?

If "Session ID" or "cookies and session ID" try changing to cookies only (leave "control panel session type" as "cookies and session ID"